# What are these two components ? I can't identify them

Tags: mosfet, identification, crystal

I'm having a hard time finding what these two components are.i can't find them anywhere.
The first one is 3 leg MOSFET which has PDB marking on it and DD on the silkscreen
The second one i can't identify it has this marking
16.0
RG5 8M

The text on the silkscreen says Q1
[image]
I need to find a similar package crystal

Comment: The second one is likely a 16 MHz crystal.

Comment: Yes thank you.but i need to find a similar one to it or the same one since this crystal has 4 legs two of them are GND.All the crystals i found have only one GND

Comment: Are you sure they are legs, and not simply solder-fillets on something like [this](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/products/6719381/)? Dimensions would help, here.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter if they are legs or pads.all i need is one similar to it that has two ground pad like this one.the dimension of it is 6.5x4mm

Answer (score 2):

The top one is possibly a [TPS3809K33DBVT](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps3809.pdf) supply voltage supervisor (2.93V), suitable for a typical 3.3V microcontroller.

The bottom one is almost certainly a 16MHz crystal, given the small NP0 capacitors on either side.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's exactly what i'm looking for

Comment: Can you tell me what that package is ? Since it has 4 legs outwards.i can't find it with SMD crystals

Comment: Are there actually legs or just pads? Looks like a standard and very common lead-less package from the photo.  Measure the dimensions and compare. Eg 3.2 x 2.5mm.

Comment: There are legs not just pads.and it has two ground legs.the dimension of it is 6.5x4mm